# how to get content out from a square bracket using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

For JavaScript, how to use regex to extract content from the a square bracket?
example:

```
var str ='1.2.3.4 - - [01/Dec/2011:11:14:42 -0800]'
var result = str.match('\[.?*\]');
```

the input `'\[.?*\]'` does not work for me even with `\ [  \ ]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myregexp = /\[(.*?)\]/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

The content of `[]` will be captured by backreference `$1`. Use the **[lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)** when doing this kind of extraction. Otherwise if you had two sets of brackets :

`[asdfjhasdf][asdfafas]` you would only get one of them from the first `[` to the last `]`

Answer (score 1):

`\[(.*)\]`
works great, dont use space after `\` and before `[` eg. `\ [` because this will not work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.  First, you need to wrap your regex in `//`.  2nd, move that `?`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ePjKM/1

```
var result = str.match(/\[.*?\]/);
```